# Injecting a script tag with ngBindHtml

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have external API data which is a user generated content. The client wants to dynamically update his own site with this feed, including the ability to use JavaScript.

```
<div ng-bind-html="post.content"></div>
```

Will display anything that is HTML or CSS but does not work with JavaScript:

```
"content":"<div>Hello Stack</div><script>alert('whats up?');</script>"
```

I have tried including `ngSanitize` as well as using `ng-bind-html-unsafe`.

No dice.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to include jQuery for this to work.

After some searching I came across https://stackoverflow.com/a/14088380/1264846.

Example plunkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/zEXXCB459Tp25VJiyyZb?p=preview

Comment: +1 It works. But that is rediculous. They call support for this "black magic" haha.