# How do I display HTML content, which is retrieved from the server using AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

Actually I have an HTML file in the server that, contains img tags, JavaScript and CSS code. I'm trying to get the content of this file using the `$http` service and display it inside a twig file using the `ng-bind-html` directive.

Until now everything is OK, but the problem is the HTML page is not displaying well, the images are not there, and the JavaScript code doesn't work.

How can I achieve this using AngularJS?

```
<div ng-repeat="language in languages" id="[[ language.name ]]" ng-bind-html="language.content" ></div>

$scope.languages={};

$http({
    method :'GET',
    url : 'url'
}).then(function(response)
{
    var results = response.data.data;
    for (var i=0; i<response.data.data.length; i++)
    {
        results[i].content = $sce.trustAsHtml(response.data.data[i].content);
    }
    $scope.languages = results;
});
```

Comment: to execute javascript you need real jquery

Comment: just try to include jquery before angular?

Comment: thnks for ur reply, but still doesn't work even if i included jquery before angular

Comment: you need to post your directive then.

Comment: thanks,  i posted the code that i'm using to retreive the html content from the server, and div tag that from within i want to display the content of file

Comment: take a look at this answer - http://stackoverflow.com/q/17460982 or add it manually with .html - http://stackoverflow.com/q/13711735

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for `ng-bind-html`. See the [docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngBindHtml). [Here](http://www.w3schools.com/angular/tryit.asp?filename=try_ng_ng-bind-html) is the example.

Comment: thanks for ur reply, but as i said i used ng-bind-html but the html page doesn't display correctly  no image is shown and also the javascript code inside the html page doesn't work

Comment: actually i'm not using $sanitize, i'm using $sce instead and its trustAsHtml method