# angular ng-bind-html ng-bind more angular code?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ng-bind-html, ng-bind

**Hello, a simple Angular question, I have:**

```
<div class="_minimal_size margin_10_middle">
    <div class="_50 espaciado_0_20">
        <p ng-bind-html="eirana_knows.feedback"></p>
    </div>
    <br class="clear"/>
</div>
```

If I bind HTML information, works perfectly fine. Now, What I'm tring to do, is to bind, actually angular code, such as {{2+2}} to give an example.

So, is there any way to make this kind of binding possible? If so, I'm looking for a simple approach, such as modifying this line:

```
        <p ng-bind-html="eirana_knows.feedback"></p>
```

For something that allows me to bind angular and process it.

**Kind regards; Chris**

Comment: didn't get what exactly you want, but going by the example, `<p ng-bind="2 + 2"></p>` works fine

Comment: when the information from the ng-bind comes from a function, let's say, grabbed from database, it doesn't show the same behaviour. It would actually print "2+2" instead of "4"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are trying inject angular code, you will want to use the $compile service:

```
var newHTML = angular.element(eirana_knows.feedback); //assuming this html
$compile(newHTML)($scope); //you would need to do this in a directive or controller where you have a scope
//then append the compiled html
someElement.append(newHTML);
```

Once you compile and inject the HTML, it will process any angular directives that are used in that HTML

Comment: shows up this way, but it's not being executed. I'm loading the variable eirana_knows.feedback with "<script type="text/javascript">alert(123);</script>" from the database. To test... but no luck so far.

Comment: You won't be able inject javascript that way as it is a huge security risk to inject and run arbitrary javascript.

Comment: I'm sure there's a way, and I don't see any security issue with that, the code is coming from my database itself, there's a few big companies doing the same if you look around.

Comment: You won't be able to do it with just Angular. You would need to do some hoop jumping with jQuery. See this SO article: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17460982/injecting-a-script-tag-with-ngbindhtml

Comment: haha, yes, I've seen it, but isn't it ridiculous? I'm using angular because I don't wanna use Jquery, and then I finally have to use Jquery to process an angular response... lol

Comment: To be fair, you aren't trying to process an angular response. Your trying to inject vanilla javascript.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't understand your reply but I believe you might lead me in the right direction. I'm working on a response system, so basically when someone inputs, let's say "facebook" on the input field, goes to a database, a checks what's the output for that, in that case it's to redirect to facebook, for that, I need to make use of a response in Javascript, and therefore I need it to be parsed. So, in other cases, lets say, when the input it "coleus bluei", the output in the database is pure HTML containing the plant information, and it works, but when it comes to Js, Angular wont parse it...