# How to include jQuery before angular in webpack with ES6?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, webpack

I've tried to have this:

```
import $ from 'jquery';
window.jQuery = $;
import angular from 'angular';
```

but $.fn.scope is undefined and scripts inside ng-bind-html don't work [Injecting a script tag with ngBindHtml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17460982/injecting-a-script-tag-with-ngbindhtml)

also tried this in webpack config

```
module.exports = {
  module: {
    loaders: [
       { test: /angular(\.min)?\.js$/, loader: "imports?$=jquery" },
       { test: /jquery(\.min)?\.js$/, loader: 'expose?jQuery' }
    ]
  }
};
```

but got error:

```
ERROR in ./~/angular/angular.js
Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve module 'expose' in C:\project\src\ui\node_modules\angular
 @ ./~/angular/angular.js 2:8-25
```

Comment: So I haven't used webpack, but I came across a similar loading issue with `requireJS` where I had to use a shim to express the module dependencies. https://github.com/webpack/docs/wiki/shimming-modules check this out for webpack shimming

Comment: @SterlingArcher your link did help, thanks.

Comment: The issue is that `import` statements get hoisted, so `window.jQuery = $;` is executed after `import angular from 'angular';`. @MrJSingh's solution is pretty good for this problem though.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

this work:

```
module.exports = {
  module: {
    loaders: [
       { test: /angular(\.min)?\.js$/, loader: "imports?$=jquery" },
       { test: /jquery(\.min)?\.js$/, loader: 'expose?jQuery' }
    ]
  }
};
```

but you need to install `expose-loader` from npm:

```
npm install expose-loader --save
```

Answer (score 3):

### Why not use a very nice and simple plugin for webpack

```
new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
  $: "jquery",
  jQuery: "jquery"
})
```

[ES6-seed with webpack and jquery](https://bitbucket.org/jorawarsingh/es6-external-files)

Comment: Whats the error? [Here is the seed which use this plugin](https://github.com/jorawarsingh/angular2-webpack-seed)

Comment: @jcubic i updated my answer with an other seed on bitbucket with ES6 and webpack.

Answer (score 1):

We used @jcubic solution in webpack 4 like this:

`npm install expose-loader imports-loader --save`

```
module: {
  rules: [
    {
      test: require.resolve('angular'),
      use: 'imports-loader?$=jquery',
    },
    {
      test: require.resolve('jquery'),
      use: [
        {
          loader: 'expose-loader',
          options: 'jQuery',
        },
        {
          loader: 'expose-loader',
          options: '$',
        },
      ],
    },
  ]
}
```