# How to execute script tags retrieved from a server

Tags: angularjs

I am working on a blog application. I would like to create posts (data stored in a database) that contains HTML and for code snippets I would like to create github gists and use the embedded script tag they provide  for displaying a gist on your site.  Thats where I'm having problems.  I can get the HTML to display just fine using ng-bind-html, but that binding seems to be stripping out the script tag.  I found this post: [Insert HTML with scripts that should run](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13711735/angular-js-insert-html-with-scripts-that-should-run/14088380#14088380). I am loading jQuery before Angular but it doesn't seem to help.  Also I'm using v1.2 and it no longer has ng-bind-html-unsafe, which is why I'm using ng-bind-html, which works perfectly except that it strips script tags.

Maybe this is just a bad idea altogether. Is there a better way to accomplish what I want?

Comment: `v1.2` has no `ng-bind-html-unsafe`? so why you're using it? is there some new feature that you need?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided to heed the warnings in the documentation and not execute a script that came from my database.  Instead I found an alternative to GitHub gists: http://alexgorbatchev.com/SyntaxHighlighter

Now I can still use HTML in my blog entry and `ng-bind-html` will sanitize it, and I can embed the syntax highlighter script in my layout. I just needed to create a directive to call it:

**Layout**

```
<article ng-repeat="blog in blogs" repeat-done="layoutDone()">
  <h4 class="title-bg">{{blog.title}}</h4>
  <div class="post-summary">
    <p ng-bind-html="blog.body"></p>
  </div><!-- /post-summary -->
</article>
```

**Directive**

```
angular.module('socketwizApp')
 .directive('repeatDone', function ($parse) {
   return {
     restrict: 'A',
     link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
       if (scope.$last) {
         var fn = $parse(attrs.repeatDone);
         fn(scope);
       };
     }
   };
 });
```

**Controller**

```
$scope.layoutDone = function() {
     $timeout(function(){
       SyntaxHighlighter.defaults.toolbar = false;
       SyntaxHighlighter.highlight();
     }, 0);
 };
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [$sce](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24sce). Particularly $sce.JS. Or you can downgrade angular but sce is a new way to do this.

Comment: From what I understand, $sce.trustAsJs(value) is the same as $sce.parseAs($sce.JS, value). I had tried that before posting. But htmlParse (https://github.com/angular/bower-angular-sanitize/blob/master/angular-sanitize.js#L217) complains about no indexOf method on html because html is not of type string but rather TrustedValueHolderType. I think that is because I'm using ng-bind-html. If I instead use ng-bind, then it doesn't seem to complain anymore, however it escapes all of the HTML including the script tag. Now if I could just figure out how to get angular to not escape the HTML ...