# Add script tag and run function inside it in runtime

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have a div tag in my view:

```
<div ng-bind-html="investmentVm.item.embed_code"></div>
```

And in my controller, I get script tag from database and put it in to model:

```
this.item.embed_code = this.$sce.trustAsHtml("<script>alert('OK');</script>");
```

If I put a html tag at the end of `embed_code`, it can be displayed by `ng-bind-html`, but script tag does not display.

In the old version of AngularJS we can use `ng-bind-html-unsafe` to bind a script tag but it has been removed in new version.

How can I add a script tag and run javascript code inside just like:

```
<script type="text/javascript">(function(n){
     //Do something here
});</script>
```

Comment: @webeno Sorry, I accidentally deleted your comment.

The script stored in database, I call to API and get it inside a json object just like :
item = {
      name: "Script name",
      owner: "quangtran",
      embed_code: "<script type="text/javascript">(function(n){ //Do  something here});</script>"
}

Comment: I guess you meant my edit, right? no worries, you can see it in history, hope you can learn from it... ;)

Comment: and if you have clarification, add it in the question, I may not be the one answering it...

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13711735/insert-html-with-scripts-that-should-run/

Comment: Thank you for your comments, I have resolved this issue by writing that `embed-code` into a template and load it into an iframe. This is not a good solution but it work fine for my case :)