# AngularJs 1.6 Component Script inside tempalteUrl not executing

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-components

I have a script tag inside the angular component's template [report.template.html] and it is not being executed upon load.

```
  <script >
  $(document).ready(function() {
  console.log("calling showHide");
  });
  </script>
```

Note: Loaded the jquery lib before angularjs lib as shown in the below plunkr

https://plnkr.co/edit/u8XGlVlY9Q5DmKmPOQwA?p=preview

I know i must be missing something simple. Can someone please help where I am doing it wrong ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Insert HTML with scripts that should run](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13711735/insert-html-with-scripts-that-should-run)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't know is this what you looking for but you an use the `angular.element(document).ready()` method instead of jquery functions like this

```
var reportController = function() {
   var ctrl = this;
      angular.element(document).ready(function () {
       console.log("calling showHide");
    });
      console.log("report ctrl");
};
```

[Demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/93b0eIcODixcjq4G0ch1?p=preview)

Comment: In my project, each report is a chart and when it is loaded, I need to execute a jquery function like $(".showhideWIdget").showhide();

Comment: you can simply do that using `ng-show/ng-hide` directive. Or you can put this in your controller also. But since you are using angular avoid using jquery as much as possible. make it all consistent with the angular

Comment: the showhide function is a custom data-widget processing js function that I need to follow as per company standard.