# Using 3rd Party Javascript in AngularJS Partials?

Tags: angularjs

I've making use of AngularJS Partial templates to create a dashboard. There is a listing view and when you click on an item, it switches to an Items-Detail partial.

Inside the Items detail partial, I'd like to show some charts via RGraph. However, for the life of me, I can't figure out how to do this.

I can't seem to invoke javascript from inside the partial html. So I think I need to do it in the controller, or maybe create a directive?

I'm pretty new to AngularJS so my understanding is still very rudimentary and likely misguided.

Comment: Normally the best way to interact with 3rd party javascript is to use directives. Can you put up a fiddler with a small example of what you're trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

AngularJS ("jqlite") doesn't support <script> tags inside partials.

Include jQuery on your page, however, and it should work.  Note that jQuery must be included before AngularJS.

See also [AngularJS: How to make angular load script inside ng-include?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12197880/angularjs-how-to-make-angular-load-script-inside-ng-include)

Comment: Other than the size of jquery, is there a reason *not* to use this method over directives? FWIW, I'm still not sure how to use directives.

Comment: @Alan, Angular purists might argue that you can rewrite just about any jQuery plugin in Angular, and that it is better to stick with one framework.  Well, then there's current reality...  zillions of jQuery plugins vs a small, but growing number of Angular projects/libraries/extensions.  So sure, use jQuery -- whatever tools get the job done. But spend some time (maybe lots of time) learning about directives and you'll likely transition to them over time.  In the [DoubleClick video/talk](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oJoAnVRIVQo), the presenter said they're using more Angular and less jQuery.