# Angularjs - Social Media Buttons Don't Show Up in Partials

Tags: angularjs, facebook, twitter, google-plus, single-page-application

I use a few social buttons in in my Angularjs app (facebook, twitter, google+). If I include these buttons in my main index.html page they show up just fine. However, if I include them in a partial and then navigate to this partial they don't show up at all. Why is this? I'm including the partial inside index.html using ng-view.

Here are scripts for the fb, twitter & g+ buttons I'm supposed to include right above the closing body tag. This lives in index.html

```
<!-- Facebook -->
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1&appId=269163553107202";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>

<!-- Google Plus - Place this tag after the last +1 button tag. -->
<script type="text/javascript">
  (function() {
    var po = document.createElement('script'); po.type = 'text/javascript'; po.async = true;
    po.src = 'https://apis.google.com/js/plusone.js';
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(po, s);
  })();
</script>     
<!-- Pinterest -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="//assets.pinterest.com/js/pinit.js"></script>
```

The buttons themselves live in my share.html partial.

```
<li class="facebook">
    <img src="/img/icon-facebook.png" alt="facebook"/>
    <div style="margin: 0 auto; display: block" class="fb-like" data-href="{{url}}" data-send="false" data-layout="button_count" data-width="450" data-show-faces="false"></div>
</li>
<li class="twitter">
  <img src="/img/icon-twitter.png" alt="twitter">
  <a style="width: 77px;" href="https://twitter.com/share" class="twitter-share-button" data-url="{{url}}" data-via="slowfoodnation" data-hashtags="">Tweet</a>
  <script>!function(d,s,id){var js,fjs=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];if(!d.getElementById(id)){js=d.createElement(s);js.id=id;js.src="//platform.twitter.com/widgets.js";fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js,fjs);}}(document,"script","twitter-wjs");</script>
</li>
<li class="google-plus">
  <img src="/img/icon-google-plus.png" alt="google plus"/>
  <!-- Place this tag where you want the +1 button to render. -->
  <div class="g-plusone" data-size="medium" data-annotation="none" data-href="{{url}}"         </div>
</li>
```

Comment: Do you have any code to show us? It's hard to say what's wrong without being able to see what you're trying.

Comment: Does your partial have `<script>` tags in it?  If so, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14329554/using-3rd-party-javascript-in-angularjs-partials

Comment: Is jQuery included before Angular?

Comment: Yes, jQuery is included before Angular

Comment: Adding jquery to the top of my partial and moving scripts from index.html to bottom of share.html did the trick. Thanks guys!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As discussed in the comments (but repeated here so this question does not show up on the "unanswered" list):  ensure jQuery is loaded, and that it is loaded before Angular.

"[jqLite](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/angular.element)" (Angular's implementation of a subset of jQuery functionality) can not handle `<script>` tags in ng-include'd partials.  If jQuery is loaded (before Angular), then Angular will use jQuery instead of jqLite.  jQuery can handle `<script>` tags in ng-include'd partials.