# java script doesnt load under angular ng-view partial pages?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, angularjs

Currently I am doing a project using angular js and bootstrap. And i am implementing some partial pages using ng-view to display those pages, but every time i am trying to using java script or jquery feature, the scripts seems not loaded, i have checked it is not a jquery conflicts problem. Please help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: please post an example

Comment: Seems to be duplicate of this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12197880/angularjs-how-to-make-angular-load-script-inside-ng-include

Answer (score 2):

Try to put link to jQuery before AngularJS in your main page.

The reason could be that AngularJS's implementation of jQuery (JQLite) do not support `<script>` tags in partials yet. But if you put jQuery before AngularJS, Angular will use "real" jQuery, that has advanced implementation of Ajax requests and special handle `<script>` tags inside loaded HTML.

Comment: This solution works for angular v1.0.7 but does not work for v1.2.0rc1. Have not found a workaround yet.

Comment: There is already issue for that: https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/3756
Should be fixed soon....