# AngularJS Javascript + $scope data

Tags: javascript, angularjs, pug, partials

So I've been trying to figure this out all day and maybe I'm just overlooking something really simple. Here's my problem: I have a nice Nodejs/AngularJS app setup that's using Jade for templating. I do some stuff on the server and eventually get some values back that are rendered in the Jade template by Angular. I have some javascript that needs to run in that view which requires those values that get passed in. However when I test it, that javascript is never run (and even if it did run I'm not sure if those values I passed in would be available to my inline javascript!)

Here's a little example of what I'm trying to do (the Jade partial):

```
script.
    //Passed in from server
    var thing = {{data.thing}}; 
    var anotherThing = {{data.anotherThing}};

    function doSomething(a, b) {};

    doSomething(thing, anotherThing);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I think I can do what I want to do with AngularJS Directives.

However, the reason why the javascript wasn't executing was because AngularJS (based on jqlite) doesn't see the < script> tags as special - so the solution is to just include the full version of jQuery before AngularJS ([source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12197880/angularjs-how-to-make-angular-load-script-inside-ng-include)).

Answer (score 0):

Im not entirely sure but I think you should try the following:

```
script.
    //Passed in from server
    var thing = "#{data.thing}"; 
    var anotherThing = "#{data.anotherThing}";

    function doSomething(a, b) {};

    doSomething(thing, anotherThing);
```

This isn't getting clear on the new jade page. They had an old doku on their github page which was more specific (you can find it [here](http://web.archive.org/web/20110317112806/https://github.com/visionmedia/jade) on webarchive, although that is quite ugly).

Hope that helps!

EDIT: [HERE](https://github.com/visionmedia/jade/blob/a751770c5d2bfe0c4d865506523247e37ec9eb5e/Readme.md) is the old version on github. This one covers far more stuff.

Comment: Hmm, still doesn't have the javascript execute.