# Yeoman - Javascript loading error

Tags: node.js, angularjs, express, yeoman

This is my app structure.

Yeoman with angular and coffee server(node+express) which gets view and public files via /app/.

View files:

```
app.set("view_engine", "html").engine "html", (path, options, fn) ->
  if "function" is typeof options
    fn = options
    options = {}
  fs.readFile path, "utf8", fn
```

Public files:

```
app.use express.static(path.resolve(__dirname + "/app/"))
```

I do load a lot of components like bootstrap, theme files,etc. HOwever, Javascript inside a view file doesnt work. It does work normally.

For example, if i remove  and replace with  for morris charts, it works. The same with ng-app and a view file with  does not load the chart.

I think the  problem is loading the js files first, since when i tried logging, the javascript file sends message before the controller for the view. So i guess the js file loads before the view thereby making the id inaccessible for the javascript file.

Please tell me how to solve this. It has been bugging me for over two days.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Probably answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12200540/1794563

Are you including jQuery **before** angularJS? If not, angularJS is using jqLite, which won't handle a situation like that.

Comment: Yeah. Angular resources come last. The same yeoman structure (yo angular command). It works when the html element is in the index file, but when the html element is in the view file, it doenst work.