# how can i load javascript file along with ng-include template

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

i am including a template into my main file using below code.

```
<p ng-include=" 'activity.html' "></p>
```

my **activity.html** goes like this,

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="myjsfile.js"></script>

<p>Activity page contents</p>
```

**But the javascript is not getting loaded along with the template**.

I found some questions related to the same in SO, but not able to find a working solution.
One of the answer says load jquery above angularjs in main file, so that the script tag will get accepted. But not found it working.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I found this answer here [load script inside ng-include](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12197880/angularjs-how-to-make-angular-load-script-inside-ng-include), Unfortunately it was not the accepted answer there. So i am providing it here with some more updates for the need.

Library link [here](https://gist.github.com/endorama/7369006#file-angular-loadscript-js)

**Create a js file contains the following script and load it in the main file.**

```
(function (ng) {
    'use strict';

    var app = ng.module('ngLoadScript', []);

    app.directive('script', function() {
        return {
            restrict: 'E',
            scope: false,
            link: function(scope, elem, attr) {
                if (attr.type=='text/javascript-lazy') {
                    var code = elem.text();
                    var f = new Function(code);
                    f();
                }
            }
        };
    });
}(angular));
```

**and, Load** `ngLoadScript` **module as application dependency:**

```
angular.module('myApp', [
    'ngLoadScript'
])
```

**in Partial (**activity.html**) use `text/javascript-lazy` as `type` attribute value for `script` tag instead of `text/javascript`:**

```
<script type="text/javascript-lazy">
    alert("Yup!");
</script>
```

**little more to do for loading external js:**

i have used below code from [ddrive](http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/loadjavascriptcss.shtml) for loading scripts (in **main.html**)

```
function loadjscssfile(filename, filetype) {
    if (filetype == "js") {
        // if filename is a external JavaScript file
        var fileref = document.createElement('script');
        fileref.setAttribute("type","text/javascript");
        fileref.setAttribute("src", filename);
    }
    else if (filetype == "css") {
        //if filename is an external CSS file
        var fileref = document.createElement("link");
        fileref.setAttribute("rel", "stylesheet");
        fileref.setAttribute("type", "text/css")
        fileref.setAttribute("href", filename)
    }
    if (typeof fileref != "undefined") {
        document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(fileref)
    }
}
```

**and in partial (activity.html):**

```
<script type="text/javascript-lazy">
    loadjscssfile("myjsfile.js", "js");
</script>
```