# ng-include won't load script nested in included html

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I´m trying to include a HTMl page with the ng-include directive into a div in my Main HTML.

Main HTML:

```
<div class="col-sm-9" data-ng-include="'subPage.html'">
    </div>
```

This SubPage is displayed correclty in the given div. Additionaly the subPage contains a script which contains some angular methods. Which i Added in the Header of SubPage.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/subService.js"></script>
```

Calling the Page with

> localhost:8080/subPage

Allowes me to use all functions and linked functions from the controller.

But when included via ng-include the Script will not even load which ofc results in no functionality. (checked in console)

Both MainPage and SubPage contain a ng-app directive and are both full standalone HTML.

Does anyone have a idea how to do this?

**UPDATE**

Like said in the answers

```
<object name="subPage" type="text/html" data="./subPage.html"></object>
```

Is a solution.But I did´t found a solution to swap them dynamcly in my body div tag.

Another Option is to load via Jquery:

```
$("#subpage_id").click(function() {
        $.getScript("js/subService.js"); 
        $("#body").load("./subPage.html");

    });
```

This solution loads the HTMl and Styles but wont any js (which is dumb because it wont load my controller js)

Comment: check this once http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20087274/how-can-i-load-javascript-file-along-with-ng-include-template

Comment: okay thanks  alot. This looks like a reasonable solution but why take the fuzz? Tested this quick <object name="subPage" type="text/html" data="./subPage.html"></object> and worked.