# Include Javascript file in Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an Angular app which redirects route to a particular html page. But how to include related javascript with this.

For example if i click red it will load red.html. but i need to load red.js also additionally.

```
   <script>
var app = angular.module("myApp", ["ngRoute"]);
app.config(function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
    .when("/", {
        templateUrl : "main.html"
    })
    .when("/red", {
        templateUrl : "red.html";
    })
    .when("/green", {
        templateUrl : "green.html"
    })
    .when("/blue", {
        templateUrl : "blue.html"
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Which version of angular?  the `angularjs` tag is used for Angular 1.x, while the `angular` tag is used for Angular 2+.  Read the tag descriptions.

Comment: I'm using Angular 1.x

Comment: Found Answer from here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20087274/how-can-i-load-javascript-file-along-with-ng-include-template

Answer (score -1):

You should use [`controller`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/provider/$routeProvider#when) property:

```
<script>
var app = angular.module("myApp", ["ngRoute"]);
app.config(function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
    .when("/", {
        controller : "MainController"
        templateUrl : "main.html"
    })
    .when("/red", {
        controller : "RedController";
        templateUrl : "red.html";
    })
    .when("/green", {
        controller : "GreenController"
        templateUrl : "green.html"
    })
    .when("/blue", {
        controller : "BlueController"
        templateUrl : "blue.html"
    });
});
</script>
<script src="controllers.js"></script> // add controllers files
```

controllers.js

```
angular
  .module('myApp')
  .controller('MainController', function() {
   //your MainController code
});

angular
  .module('myApp')
  .controller('RedController', function() {
   //your RedController code
});

angular
  .module('myApp')
  .controller('GreenController', function() {
   //your GreenController code
});

angular
  .module('myApp')
  .controller('BlueController', function() {
   //your BlueController code
});
```

Comment: I want to include js files. In Controller can't add this line
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/red.js"></script>

Comment: you should add in in red.html and it will be loaded in same scope of your controller