# Including <script>s in my Angular views

Tags: javascript, angularjs, saucelabs

When I paste *any* `<script>` into my angular view, it fails silently and does not load the script.

I'm trying to embed a Saucelabs video into my AngularJS project. [(**Documentation**](https://saucelabs.com/docs/integration#embedding-video), [**example script**)](https://saucelabs.com/video-embed/7dcb077bfcfd43a0a9d50011dd3bc01c.js?auth=6a7dcf9f2d8e7039699bd0280a7f4504)

```
<script src="https://saucelabs.com/video-embed/<jobId>.js?auth=<authToken>"></script>
```

However, pasting `<script>alert('test')</script>` into my view doesn't appear to work either, so I'm thinking this is default behaviour of Angular.

Clearly, *logic* doesn't really belong in the view, so generally I don't need to include any `<script>`s here, but in this case, I don't really see an alternative.

Any ideas?

Comment: ah, good find, I *did* search for duplicates, but did not find that... let me verify that this indeed is the same situation...

Comment: ... and it *is* the same situation, but [this question's answers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12197880/angularjs-how-to-make-angular-load-script-inside-ng-include) seem to be better.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a hack I am using for loading scripts in the controller.

Btw, I put in into `resolve` of the view/state to wait till script loads.

```
$http.get('http://api-maps.yandex.ru/2.0/?load=package.full&lang=ru-RU').then(function(data){
    window.eval(data);
    deffered.resolve() // because I'm using it in the resolve part
});
```

Specify your own URL and thats works.

Another option could be using RequireJS, but I've not used it.

Comment: Hmmm, I'll give this a try (on Monday), but I kinda think it won't work. The [script in question](https://saucelabs.com/video-embed/7dcb077bfcfd43a0a9d50011dd3bc01c.js?auth=6a7dcf9f2d8e7039699bd0280a7f4504) looks like it actually requires the `<script>` tag to be present, as thats how it knows where to inject the html (but I may be confused)

Comment: `<script>` tag is actually loading remote script and evaluates (runs) it. My code does the same. It will inject the code on the global scope, because I use eval on the window object.