# Embed javascript in angular ui-router view

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, jquery-ui, angular-ui-router

I'm really sorry if this has already been answered, but I have no idea how to search for it since it seems so specific.

I've got an AngularJS app using ui-router to dynamically load multiple views into the same `<ui-view>` element. I want to use Jquery UI's tooltip function on one of the h3 elements loaded dynamically by ui-router, but I don't know where to put the initializer such that it runs after the h3 is in the DOM.

Things I've tried:

- Embedding a `<script>` tag in the HTML partial that calls `$("h3").tooltip()`
- Putting the script tag in the main parent HTML template - with and without a `document.ready` wrapper
- Putting the `tooltip()` function call in one of the angular js files that's loading the partial (when I changed the line to just `alert()`, it seemed that this code was running right before the partial is rendered, so there are no `<h3>`s yet)

I'm very confused as to how I can run arbitrary javascript code on dynamically loaded elements ... I think the first method should have worked. Even when I make the `<script>` tag just contain a simple `alert()`, nothing happens.

Any ideas? I'm also happy to provide more information, but I think I can't show the actual code due to an NDA.

Answer (score 0):

may these will help you:

[Embed javascript in angular ui-router view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22885044/embed-javascript-in-angular-ui-router-view)

[AngularJS: How to make angular load script inside ng-include?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12197880/angularjs-how-to-make-angular-load-script-inside-ng-include)

Answer (score 0):

The approach you are taking to get that tooltip working is very wrong. Instead of trying to load a script dynamically inside a view, you should be wrapping the tooltip plugin inside a directive and assigning that directive to your h3 element. Or, even simpler, use Angular UI Bootstrap's Tooltip directive: http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/

Mock code for custom directive:

```
'use strict';

angular.module('MyModule')
    .directive('tooltip', function () {
        return {
            restrict: 'A',
            link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
                // initialize jQuery tooltip
                // note element is a jqLite object with jQuery methods available
                // DO NOT ATTEMPT TO WRAP element WITH jQuery
                // ANGULAR CANNOT TRACK jQuery OBJECTS THAT
                //   ARE NOT WRAPPED WITH jqLite!!!
                element.tooltip(...);
            }
        };
    });
```