# Angularjs templateUrl fails to bind attributes inside ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-repeat

I'm using directive to display html snippets.

And templateUrl inside the directive, 
to be able to include snippets as html file.

The directive does not work, if I try to call
inside a builtin ng-repeat directive 
({{snip}} is passed as is, without substitute):

```
div ng-repeat="snip in ['snippet1.html','snippet2.html']">
  <my-template snippet="{{snip}}"></my-template>
</div>
```

For reference, here is the directive:

```
app.directive("myTemplate", function() {
return {
    restrict: 'EA',
    replace: true,
    scope: { snippet: '@'},
    templateUrl: function(elem, attrs) {
      console.log('We try to load the following snippet:' + attrs.snippet);
      return attrs.snippet;
    }
  };
});
```

And also a [plunker demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/woeJlslfk97W6Xhhvwe7?p=preview).

Any pointer is much appreciated.
(the directive is more complicated in my code, 
I tried to get a minimal example, where the issue is reproducible.)

Comment: posable duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21835471/angular-js-directive-dynamic-templateurl

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`attrs` param for `templateUrl` is not interpolated during directive execution. You may use the following way to achieve this

```
app.directive("myTemplate", function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'EA',
    replace: false,
    scope: { snippet: '@'},
    template: '<div ng-include="snippet"></div>'
  };
});
```

Demo: http://plnkr.co/edit/2ofO6m45Apmq7kbYWJBG?p=preview

Comment: This **is** a workaround. The final DOM looks like this: `<my-template><div class="ng-scope" ng-include="snippet"><div>` the contant of my snippet `</div></div></my-template>`. Thank you for the idea.

Comment: @Doug, Rajeshwar and you gave basically identicaly solution. I'm marking your response as solution, because you are using one way databinding (@), instead of two way databinding (=) or $observe, so It is slightly more elegant. A small modification `'@'` should be `'@snippet'`, the directive only needs this variable from its parent scope. I don't like the fact, the template file is embedded in the DOM tree two additional level deep. But pankajparkar solution is maybe overkill.

Comment: I ended up modifying these two lines: `scope: { snippet: '@snippet'},` and `template: '<div ng-include="\'app/partials/\' + snippet"></div>'`. Could you please update your answer, and also include everything from [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/kEaIF7INQTezSl48pNv8?p=info) for archiving reasons? (html, js, two snippets)

Answer (score 1):

Check out this link

http://plnkr.co/edit/TBmTXztOnYPYxV4qPyjD?p=preview

```
app.directive("myTemplate", function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'EA',
    replace: true,
    scope: { snippet: '=snippet'},
    link: function(scope, elem, attrs) {
      console.log('We try to load the following snippet:' + scope.snippet);
    },
    template: '<div ng-include="snippet"></div>'
  };
})
```

Comment: You are not including the **content** of the html snippets, rather you are displaying the **filename** of the html snippets. Can you adapt your solution to include the content of the snippets?

Comment: @arcol, Please check the same plunker link, the changes you mentioned are implemented.

Comment: ng-include will create isolated scope again

Answer (score 0):

You can use [ng-include](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInclude), watching the attrs. Like this:

```
app.directive("myTemplate", function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        replace: true,
        link: function(scope, elem, attrs) {
            scope.content = attrs.snippet;
            attrs.$observe("snippet",function(v){
                scope.content = v;
            });
        },
        template: "<div data-ng-include='content'></div>"
    };
});
```

Comment: In your directive the scope.content will have value 'snip', not the value we pass from markup.

Answer (score 0):

Just made changes in directive structure. Instead of rendering all templates using `ng-repeat` we will render it using directive itself, for that we will pass entire template array to directive.

**HTML**

```
<div ng-init="snippets = ['snippet1.html','snippet2.html']">
    <my-template snippets="snippets"></my-template>
</div>
```

**Directive**

```
angular.module('myApp', [])
.controller('test',function(){})
    .directive("myTemplate", function ($templateCache, $compile) {
    return {
        restrict: 'EA',
        replace: true,
        scope: {
            snippets: '='
        },
        link: function(scope, element, attrs){
            angular.forEach(scope.snippets, function(val, index){
                //creating new element inside angularjs
                element.append($compile($templateCache.get(val))(scope));
            });
        }
    };
});
```

[**Working Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/kzX9z/41/)

Hope this could help you. Thanks.

Comment: It was not specified in the original request, but I would like the html snippets in separate files. Which looks regular html and can be edited by a third party (ie. web designer). Reading [$templateCache](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$templateCache) documentation, you either use $templateCache.put with a string, or you put the template in the main html via `<script type="text/ng-template" id="templateId.html">` tag. Do I miss something obvious?

Comment: @arcol you are correct and also you can put in `html` too..only you need to put those html template to `$templateCache` at the run phase of angular. refer this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27785564/run-a-function-after-all-partials-ng-includes-loaded/27786046#27786046

Comment: You need to do only this `app.run(['$templateCache','$q','$http', function($templateCache, $http){
$http.get('partials/views/template1.html',{ cache : $templateCache });
$http.get('partials/views/template2.html',{ cache : $templateCache });
}]);` to put html inside `$templateCache`

Comment: I tried to get it work with your solution, but I got stuck: http://plnkr.co/edit/IYZHcmSkX7zkM9o0NEFe

Answer (score 0):

it seems you are trying to have different views based on some logic 
and you used templateUrl function but Angular interpolation was not working, to fix this issue

> don't use `templateUrl`

so how to do it without using templateUrl

simply like this

```
app.directive("myTemplate", function() {
    return {
        link: function(scope, elem, attrs) {
           $scope.templateUrl = '/ActivityStream/activity-' + $scope.ativity.type + '.html'
        },
        template: "<div data-ng-include='templateUrl'></div>"
    };
});
```

hope this is simple and esay to understand