# How should I specify a schema.org Date in Angular 2?

Tags: angular, schema.org

Schema.org recommends specifying dates and times using the `time` element with the `datetime` attribute - [see docs](http://schema.org/docs/gs.html#advanced_dates) e.g.

```
<time datetime="SOMEISODATETIME">3 April 1955</time>
```

However Angular 2 only allows binding to properties and it seems that `datetime` is only an attribute and not a property. Trying to bind as follows ...

```
<time datetime="{{ myDate | date:'y-MM-dd' }}">{{ myDate | date:'YYYY MM DD' }}</time>
```

therefore causes errors ...

```
Unhandled Promise rejection: Template parse errors:
Can't bind to 'datetime' since it isn't a known property of 'time'. ("prop="headline" itemprop="name">{{ newsItem.title }}</h2>
            <time class="published-date" [ERROR ->]
```

How should I get around this?

Comment: Have you tried `[attr.datetime]="..."`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use Angular 2 extrapolation in html element attributes?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36099392/how-to-use-angular-2-extrapolation-in-html-element-attributes)

Comment: @jonrsharpe that worked -  had completely forgotton about the `attr.XXX` binding syntax. Thanks!

Comment: I'm not sure they are duplicates ... they have the same answer but are different questions. If they are too similar however I can accept the duplicate. By this do you mean close, delete or something else?

Comment: If they have the same answer, that's what people who find this question will be looking for, surely? Note **your question may already have an answer here**.

Comment: Right, my point is though I did my due diligence and searched for an answer (using the error message) and came up empty hence me asking this question - the referred question did not have any error messages and reads like a completely different problem. If I delete this question then someone searching via an error message, like I did, won't find the answer! If this is SO policy then I'll delete but it seems weird since so many varied, distinct questions do have the same ultimate solution ...

Comment: I'm not saying you should delete it, I'm saying you should accept the duplicate. It's useful as a signpost, *if that signpost points to the canonical resources*. See https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/11/dr-strangedupe-or-how-i-learned-to-stop-worrying-and-love-duplication/ I find it surprising that someone with 10k rep is unfamiliar with this process.

Comment: There is no clear 'accept duplicate' button, just a close button and delete button

Comment: Should look like this: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/250930/248731

Comment: Hmm that did appear at one point but I edited, now it doesn't appear (as spec'ed in the meta post)  - I just voted to close myself citing duplicate but the 'accept duplicate' UI hasn't re-appeared - can someone else vote to close citing duplicate?

Comment: Yep, that'll have to be it - only one more vote needed. I assumed the OP's vote would be binding even if not via that dialog.

Comment: Not sure why peeps are so excited about marking this duplicate. It's a distinct question, even if the answer is similar to or the same as another, different question. 

For me, the real answer was actually pointed out in the question itself: it's an attribute. Had marking this question duplicate lowered its search rank, it might have taken me longer to be reminded of that fact.

I hope people mark this question up, because it was a well-phrased, valuable question that is NOT directly answered elsewhere on SO. The author deserves the points.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use `[attr.datetime]`

```
<time [attr.datetime]="date:'y-MM-dd'">{{ date | date:'dd MMM yyyy' }}</time>
```

You had the format wrong for the displayed date too. [DatePipe docs](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/common/index/DatePipe-pipe.html)