# How to load scripts in <script> tag within a template by $routeProvider?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, amd

My `router.coffee` (`module.exports` is from browerify) looks like this:

```
module.exports = [
  '$routeProvider'
  ($routeProvider) ->
    $routeProvider
    .when '/',
      templateUrl: 'home.html'
      controller: 'HomeCtrl'
    .when '/signup',
      templateUrl: 'signup.html'
      controller: 'SignUpCtrl'
    .when '/signin',
      templateUrl: 'signin.html'
      controller: 'SignInCtrl'
    .when '/map',
      templateUrl: 'map.html'
      controller: 'MapCtrl'
    .otherwise redirectTo: '/'
    return
]
```

My `map.html` looks like this:

```
<div class="container">
    <script src='//maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false'></script>
    <ui-gmap-google-map center='map.center' zoom='map.zoom'></ui-gmap-google-map>
</div>
```

My `index.html` looks like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="app">
<head>
  <title>Mytest</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/app.css" media="all"/>
</head>
<body id="page-top"  ng-view>
</body>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/app.js"></script>
</html>
```

The problem is :

when I visit `mydomain/#/map`, the `<script src='//maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false'></script>`
 will not be loaded.. Is there a way to load the script when a template is loaded by `ng-view`?

Comment: See this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12197880/angularjs-how-to-make-angular-load-script-inside-ng-include

Comment: will map script line added into index page

Comment: Check this..it may helps you.. http://www.amasik.com/execute-script-in-each-partial-loads/