# How to include 3rd party javascript libraries in AngularJS partial template?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs, templates

I have got a simple example to try to figure out why my angular partial template can not load another javascript component.

I am using 1 template (singleArticleView.html) and a parent page(blog.html)and i am trying to apply run_prettify.js to a simple code snippet inside of my template. If the code is inside of the template it does not work. If i remove the code and the script tags from the child template and include them inside of the parent it works properly

How can I execute that javascript library inside my template? I think it does not work because DOM elements have loaded later.

***How can I evaluate if the content in the partial template is already rendered in order to execute any external javascript code to manipulate the DOM?***

I appreciate any suggestion

It is the code:

blog.html (Parent)

```
   <script src="~/AngularJS/Controllers/articlesController.js"></script>
    <script src="~/AngularJS/Controllers/singleArticleController.js"></script>
            <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-1">
                        <div data-ng-view>
                        </div>
                    </div>
            </div>
```

singleArticleView.html (template)

```
            <script src="~/Scripts/run_prettify.js"></script>
            <link href="~/Content/prettify.css" rel="stylesheet" />

                         <div>
                                {{article.author }}
                                <pre class="prettyprint linenums lang-html">
                                            &lt;!DOCTYPE html&gt;
                                            &lt;html&gt;
                                              &lt;head&gt;
                                                &lt;title&gt;Demo | Prettify.JS&lt;/title&gt;
                                              &lt;/head&gt;
                                              &lt;body&gt;
                                                &lt;h1&gt;Hello, World!&lt;/h1&gt;
                                              &lt;/body&gt;
                                            &lt;/html&gt;
                                </pre>

                            </div>
```

singleArticleControlle.js (controller)

```
(function () {
                var app = angular.module("dbayonaCode");
                var singleArticleController = function ($scope, dataService, $window, $routeParams, $sce) {

                    $scope.article = {};
                    $scope.newComment = {};
                    //Get the article with its comments to show in the template and add a new comment
                    //It uses ArticlesController.cs
                    dataService.getArticleById($routeParams.id)
                     .then(function (data) {
                         //success
                         $scope.article = data;
                         $scope.myContent = $sce.trustAsHtml(data.body);

                     },

                     function () {
                         //error
                         $windows.location = "#/";

                     });

                }
                app.controller("singleArticleController", singleArticleController);
            }());
```

Answer (score 1):

This is normal behavior for angular, which strips script tags from templates.

I found a couple solutions, depending on exactly what you are trying to do.  If it's a smaller script and you can just inline it, I like this solution here which adds a 'lazy-loading' type to the script tag:

```
/*global angular */
(function (ng) {
  'use strict';

  var app = ng.module('ngLoadScript', []);

  app.directive('script', function() {
    return {
      restrict: 'E',
      scope: false,
      link: function(scope, elem, attr) {
        if (attr.type === 'text/javascript-lazy') {
          var code = elem.text();
          var f = new Function(code);
          f();
        }
      }
    };
  });

}(angular));
```

The above code comes from this post: [AngularJS: How to make angular load script inside ng-include?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12197880/angularjs-how-to-make-angular-load-script-inside-ng-include)

The problem is that it only loads the text between the script tags and won't load a file specified in the `src` attribute.

A different solution also modifies the script directive and allows us to load external js files via the `src` attribute, or from between the script tag if `src` is undefined:

```
/*global angular */
(function (ng) {
  'use strict';

  var app = ng.module('ngLoadScript', []);

  app.directive('script', function() {
    return {
      restrict: 'E',
      scope: false,
      link: function(scope, elem, attr) 
      {
        if (attr.type==='text/javascript-lazy') 
        {
          var s = document.createElement("script");
          s.type = "text/javascript";                
          var src = elem.attr('src');
          if(src!==undefined)
          {
              s.src = src;
          }
          else
          {
              var code = elem.text();
              s.text = code;
          }
          document.head.appendChild(s);
          elem.remove();
        }
      }
    };
  });

}(angular));
```

The above code snippet comes from [here](https://gist.github.com/subudeepak/9617483#file-angular-loadscript-js).

Comment: i am not using ngInclude, i am using ng-view. However I have created the js file with that content and calling that file after I call the controller assigned to that template. I guess the name "ngLoadScript" on that line " var app = ng.module('ngLoadScript', []);" is the name of my module.  I dont know what exactly they guys in the other links mean with "load ngLoadScript module as application dependency".? , anyway, i can see that the client is getting the js files using the  'lazy-loading' tag, now i am getting a console error:"Uncaught Error: can't load XRegExp twice in the same frame" :(

Comment: Look at the plunker I have it working with ng-transcode and ng-view.

Comment: Could you please send me the link to the plunker example. Thanks

Comment: Sorry I see now I neglected to include it.  I'll post it shortly

Comment: Could u please include it as a comment. I would really appreciate it.

Comment: Just use the second code snippet in your module and include your script like you normally would.