# Running script within ui-router TemplateURL

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angular-ui-router

I currently have a single page web application using Angular and UI-Router.  The majority of my javascript files are being loaded on my index.html page, and those all work perfectly throughout the application.

Issue:  I have a state that requires javascript code to run when the state is called.  (When ui-router injects the html from this state's particular templateURL into the ui-view, I need the javascript within the injected html to run). I have been searching all day and have tried various solutions but nothing has worked.

Is there a best practice for adding this functionality? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not clear, but I assume the issue is that the `script` tags in the HTML you're injecting aren't being run. Instead of using the standard `script` tag, you need to instead create a directive that allows you to do this. See Paolo's answer on [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12197880/angularjs-how-to-make-angular-load-script-inside-ng-include) for instructions on how to do that.

Note that you're assuming some of the responsibility for script security if you do this.

Comment: That looks exactly like what I'm trying to do.  So would I have to create a separate directive for every javascript file that needs to be loaded into a state (not a big deal, but curious)?  What is the last step, just including the element from the directive in my state's templateURL.  For example, Paolo would then include <lazyload></lazyload> within the templateUrl for the state he's loading the google api into? Thanks.

Comment: @user2263572: nope, once you write the directive you can re-use it anywhere. You'll need at most two: one to run javascript embedded directly in the HTML you're trying to include (for example something like, `<run-script>var foo = "bar";...</run-script>`) and one to load javascript from another location (like `<load-script url="http://cdn.foo.com/mylib/1.0"></load-script>`). Just change the `script` tags in the HTML you're trying to include to the appropriate directive and you're set.

Comment: I was able to get lazy loading working for both types of scripts.  Unfortunately, although the lazyloading works with my test scripts, it didn't work with the google charts API that I was trying to lazyload.  If you think you have any idea why the new question can be found here. [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30894544/angular-ui-router-lazyloading-google-charts)  Thanks again for the help, i made some solid progress.