# Whats a good and and simple workaround to ng-include not loading scripts?

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

In my Web App, I have to use `ng-include` to dynamically load content. However, this content also contains scripts (preferably even additional Controllers), which ng-include [doesnt load](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/3756).

None of the approaches I found are really satisfying.

I thought perhaps something like

```
<div>contentUrl.onChanged{ load HTML and load/execute scripts}</div>
```

to replace

```
<div ng-include="contentUrl"></div>
```

However, I couldn't find anything and my JavaScript-knowledge is not yet sufficient to do this myself.

Comment: Haha I read through about 20 Questions about this before I found the Question you just posted.
By then I was too frustrated to scroll further than the accepted answer - turns out the solution was just beneath that. Now I feel stupid. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

The answer can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12197880/angularjs-how-to-make-angular-load-script-inside-ng-include). Pay Attention, its not the accepted answer ;)
Thanks @James Bierley

> Here's a quick fix created by endorama:
>
> /*global angular */
>   (function (ng) {
>    'use strict';
>
> var app = ng.module('ngLoadScript', []);
>
> app.directive('script', function() {
>    return {
>     restrict: 'E',
>    scope: false,
>   link: function(scope, elem, attr) {
>    if (attr.type === 'text/javascript-lazy') {
>     var code = elem.text();
>    var f = new Function(code);
>   f();
>   }
>    }
>   };
>   });
>
> }(angular));
>
> Simply add this file, load ngLoadScript module as application dependency and use
>
> type="text/javascript-lazy" as type for script you which to load lazily in >partials:
>
> console.log("It works!");

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: Changed that. The Quote function is a pain in the backside -.-