# How to load html file with scripting in AngularJs view?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

This is my code

```js
template.html:-
  
   <div ng-controller="TempCtrl">
    <h2>About</h2>
    <h3>{{total}}</h3>
    <p>Testing the total</p>
    <button ng-click="update()">Update</button>
</div>

<script>
    console.log("begin")
    angular.module("app")
    .controller("TempCtrl", function ($scope) {
        $scope.total = 0;
        console.log("inside")
        $scope.update = function () {
            total += total;
        };
    });
    console.log("end")
</script>
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="app" ng-controller="AppCtrl">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
        <title>Web</title>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.9/angular.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container body-content">
            <div class="dynamic-content" >No data  Yet
                <!-- Loading content Here -->
            </div>
            <button ng-click="loadTemplate()">Load Template</button>
         
        </div>

        <script>
            var app = angular.module('app', []);
            
            app.config(
                function( $controllerProvider, $provide, $compileProvider ) {
                
                    app.controller = function( name, constructor ) {
                        $controllerProvider.register( name, constructor );
                        return( this );
                    };
                
                }
            );
            
            app.controller('AppCtrl', function ($scope) {
              $scope.show=false;
                $scope.someData = {};
                $scope.loadTemplate = function() {
                  $scope.show=true;
                    var container = $('.dynamic-content');
                   container.html('<div ng-controller="TempCtrl"> <h2>About</h2> <h3>{{total}}</h3> <p>Testing the total</p> <button ng-click="update()">Update</button> </div> <script> console.log("begin"); console.log(app.controller); app.controller("TempCtrl", function ($scope) { $scope.total = 0; console.log("inside"); $scope.update = function () { $scope.total = $scope.total + 1; }; }); console.log("end") <\/script>');                  
                 var newScope = angular.element(container).scope();
                   var compile = angular.element(container).injector().get('$compile');
                  compile($(container).contents())(newScope);
                }
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

In the above code was working fine but using Jquery. i am getting template.html source from web api services . when i click button (loadtemplate) that time i want to show the template.html source. In that template.html file contains angular scripting also. i am trying to use ng-include directive but that was not working because that html file contains angular script. Now how to load that html file using Angularjs or javascript only not using Jquery.

[Link Reference](https://plnkr.co/edit/EAa9Md36hDzpQ1BgIQKg?p=preview)

Comment: The following question might give some pointers: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12197880/angularjs-how-to-make-angular-load-script-inside-ng-include