# FormSite Form Embedding into Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, forms

I created a form using [Formsite](https://www.formsite.com/) and I am having trouble embedding the code into my page. Their embed code from their site looks something like [this](https://fs27.formsite.com/documentation/embedded-form.html#embed_code_options):

```
<a name="formvtjqi9JE" id="formAnchorvtjqi9JE"></a>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//www.formsite.com/include/form/embedManager.js?vtjqi9JE"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
EmbedManager.embed({
 key: "www.formsite.com/form_app/Formsite?EParam=IRLY%2&vtjqi9JE",
 width: "100%",
 prePopulate: { "2":"Alex", "3":"Powers","4-1":"1","4-2":"2"},
 resizeCallback: yourFunction,
 showFormLogin: false,
 mobileResponsive: true
});
</script>
```

My page won't load the javascript file directly on the page since it uses controllers for all of it's javascript. Is there a way to load this script into a controller? I think my issue is related to this [AngularJS: How to make angular load script inside ng-include?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12197880/angularjs-how-to-make-angular-load-script-inside-ng-include) but I wasn't able to get that working with the embed code.

**Sidenote**

I know the embed code works because if I create a blank html page and just copy and paste the embed code it will appear.

**Clarification** (apologies in advance I am just learning angular)

The format of the site looks like it keeps everything in the `index.html` so this page only has all of the scripts which look something like this

```
<link href="vendor/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="css/main.css" rel="stylesheet"><!-- main.css is output from main.scss, NOT A WORKING FILE -->

<!-- Theme CSS -->
<link href="vendor/pictonic/css/pictonic.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="img/header/syn_emblem.png">

<!-- HTML5 Shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
<!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
<script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/html5shiv/3.7.0/html5shiv.js"></script>
<script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/respond.js/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
<![endif]-->

<script src="vendor/angular/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="vendor/angular/angular-ui-router.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/myapp.js"></script>
<script src="./vendor/pictonic/js/pictonic.min.js"></script>

<!-- typekit fonts -->
<script src="https://use.typekit.net/yqg2zpp.js"></script>
<script>try{Typekit.load({ async: true });}catch(e){}</script>

<!-- directives -->


<!-- controllers -->
<script src="js/home.controller.js"></script>
<script src="js/navigationController.js"></script>
<script src="js/survey.controller.js"></script>
```

**Attempt 1**

I have another html which is the survey.html where I want to put the form I created. But if I just copy and paste the embedded code from above into this nothing appears. This page doesn't have any `<script>` tags in it's html so I am guessing that I have to put the embed code somewhere else which leads to...

**Attempt 2**
I took the line

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//www.formsite.com/include/form/embedManager.js?vtjqi9JE"></script>
```

and put that into the `index.html` and I am trying to take the second script portion of that and put that into the `survey.controller.js` so that portion I am adding is looking something like.

```
(function (ng) {
'use strict';

var surveyPage = ng.module('ngLoadScript', []);

surveyPage.directive('script', function() {
 return {
   restrict: 'E',
    scope: false,
    link: function(scope, elem, attr) {
      EmbedManager.embed({
      key: "https://fs27.formsite.com/res/showFormEmbed?EParam=blabla",
      width: "100%",
      mobileResponsive: true
      });
    }
  };
});

}(angular));
```

Which doesn't work either.

Comment: What do you mean when you say "My page won't load the javascript file directly on the page since it uses controllers for all of it's javascript"? Why can you not just include it as part of the template? Can you post some example code of your controller and template you are trying to add this to?

Comment: Sorry it confusing. I am still learning angular and I am trying to make changes to this webpage so the structure is new to me. I added an explanation as best as I could. If anything else needs clarifying or needs more information just tell me.