# angular sanitize throwing error while using script tag on the variable

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-sanitizer

Trying to implement the angular sanitizer on my application using angular sanitizer  but it's not working as expected.

```js
angular.module('sanitizeExample', ['ngSanitize'])
      .controller('ExampleController', ['$scope', '$sce', function($scope, $sce) {
      //$scope.snippet = "<script type='text/javascript'>alert(1)</script>";
      $scope.snippet = "alert(1)";
      $scope.deliberatelyTrustDangerousSnippet = function() {
         return $sce.trustAsHtml($scope.snippet);
      };
      $scope.escape = function(input) {
        return $sce.trustAsHtml(input);
      }
  }]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.8/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.8/angular-sanitize.js"></script>

<div ng-app="sanitizeExample">
    <div ng-controller="ExampleController">
        Snippet: <textarea ng-model="snippet" cols="60" rows="3"></textarea>
       <table>
         <tr>
           <td>Directive</td>
           <td>How</td>
           <td>Source</td>
           <td>Rendered</td>
         </tr>
         <tr id="bind-html-with-sanitize">
           <td>ng-bind-html</td>
           <td>Automatically uses $sanitize</td>
           <td><pre>&lt;div ng-bind-html="snippet"&gt;<br/>&lt;/div&gt;</pre></td>
           <td><div ng-bind-html="snippet"></div></td>
         </tr>
         <tr id="bind-html-with-trust">
           <td>ng-bind-html</td>
           <td>Bypass $sanitize by explicitly trusting the dangerous value</td>
           <td>
           <pre>&lt;div ng-bind-html="deliberatelyTrustDangerousSnippet()"&gt;
&lt;/div&gt;</pre>
           </td>
           <td><div ng-bind-html="deliberatelyTrustDangerousSnippet()"></div></td>
         </tr>
         <tr id="bind-default">
           <td>ng-bind</td>
           <td>Automatically escapes</td>
           <td><pre>&lt;div ng-bind="snippet"&gt;<br/>&lt;/div&gt;</pre></td>               <td><div ng-bind="snippet">ggg</div></td>
           </tr>
       </table>
       <p>{{ escape("<script type='text/javascript'>alert(1)</script>") }}</p>
       </div>
</div>
```

Throws Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token error while using the script

> `$scope.snippet = "<script type='text/javascript'>alert(1)</script>"`

Works fine without script

```
$scope.snippet = "alert(1)"
```

It gives the alert in the browser but expecting the innertext for the p tag.

```
<p>{{ escape("<script type='text/javascript'>alert(1)</script>") }}</p>
```

also getting the output in the html

> {{ escape("") }}

How to do the sanitizing the variable which has the script tag also by calling the controller function from the html template .

Comment: take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12197880/angularjs-how-to-make-angular-load-script-inside-ng-include

Comment: I am looking xss attack sanitize fix.

Comment: my requirement is to display the script also as text inside the html template.

Answer (score 1):

this works?

```js
    angular.module("sanitizeExample", ['ngSanitize'])
        .controller("ExampleController", ['$scope', '$sce', function($scope, $sce){
        /* $scope.snippet = "alert(1)"; */
        $scope.snippet = "<script " + "type='text/javascript'"+" >alert(1) <" + "/script>";
        $scope.deliberatelyTrustDangerousSnippet = function(){
            return $sce.trustAsHtml($scope.snippet);
        };
        $scope.escape = function(input) {
            return $sce.trustAsHtml(input);
        }
    }]);
```

```html
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.8/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.8/angular-sanitize.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    
    <div ng-app="sanitizeExample">
        <div ng-controller="ExampleController">
            Snippet: <textarea ng-model="snippet" cols="60" rows="3"></textarea>
           <table>
             <tr>
               <td>Directive</td>
               <td>How</td>
               <td>Source</td>
               <td>Rendered</td>
             </tr>
             <tr id="bind-html-with-sanitize">
               <td>ng-bind-html</td>
               <td>Automatically uses $sanitize</td>
               <td><pre>&lt;div ng-bind-html="snippet"&gt;<br/>&lt;/div&gt;</pre></td>
               <td><div ng-bind-html="snippet"></div></td>
             </tr>
             <tr id="bind-html-with-trust">
               <td>ng-bind-html</td>
               <td>Bypass $sanitize by explicitly trusting the dangerous value</td>
               <td>
               <pre>&lt;div ng-bind-html="deliberatelyTrustDangerousSnippet()"&gt;
    &lt;/div&gt;</pre>
               </td>
               <td><div ng-bind-html="deliberatelyTrustDangerousSnippet()"></div></td>
             </tr>
             <tr id="bind-default">
               <td>ng-bind</td>
               <td>Automatically escapes</td>
               <td><pre>&lt;div ng-bind="snippet"&gt;<br/>&lt;/div&gt;</pre></td>               <td><div ng-bind="snippet">ggg</div></td>
               </tr>
           </table>
           <!-- 
        -->
               <p>{{ escape("<script type='text/javascript'>alert(1)</script>") }}</p>
           </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Only inclusive of the ngSanitize module enough to do the sanitize from in the view.

```
angular.module("sanitizeExample", ['ngSanitize'])
```

This is not the correct way to test the sanitize from the view. It passes as variable to the angular so that it's executing and gives the alert.

```
{{ escape("<script type='text/javascript'>alert(1)</script>") }}
```

When we test from the data services sanitize is working as expected.