# ng-controller within an include that is within another controller potential scope issue

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angularjs-scope

I am using node and angularjs. I have a frame like page inside an ejs that is passed content to load into the includes dynamically.

```
<div ng-app="thisApp">
  <div ng-controller='MainCtrl'>
     {{ firstMessage }}
     <div id='contentFromNode' ng-include='<%= pageContent %>'></div>
  </div>
</div>
<script>
    var thisApp = angular.module('thisApp', []);
    thisApp.controller('MainCtrl', [ '$scope', function($scope) {
         $scope.firstMessage = "Main Controller Working Fine";
    }])
</script>
```

and then the passed content might be just an html page containing something like this:

```
<div ng-controller='NestedCtrl' id='content-type-container'>
    {{ nestedMessage }}
</div>
<script>
     thisApp.controller('NestedCtrl', [function(){
         var nested = this;
         nested.nestedMessage = "Nested Won't Work";
     }])
</script>
```

So I have tried $scope within the NestCtrl instead of referencing this, I have tried moving the script tag above and below (ideally this get separated eventually anyway). I have tried aliasing the controllers, however my problem is the in registration of the controller itself as I get that great `Error: [$controller:ctrlreg]` error. The page is loading the content fine? Any ideas what I am doing wrong here?

Comment: are you declaring "myApp" to angular.module?

Comment: yeah that is mistake, correction made

Comment: Maybe this code help you
https://codesandbox.io/s/54p322r2p

Answer (score 0):

Seems JQlite doesn't support this. You have to include jquery or lazy load the script. Refer

[AngularJS: How to make angular load script inside ng-include?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12197880/angularjs-how-to-make-angular-load-script-inside-ng-include)